# How time is updated when tick interrupts are disabled

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

After reading the Linux manual-

[Understanding The Linux Kernel](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/UnderstandingTheLinuxKernel3rdEdition.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi6zN7a6qfWAhUH1hoKHf7MAGoQFggjMAA&usg=AFQjCNEIWdghVX16FREMGa_rzYfIG062Gw)

I'm left with unsolved question. The tick interrupt handler is where the kernel keeps the time data structures updated. In the manual there is a very limited explenation regarding recovering lost tick interrupts, for example-

> cur_timer points to the timer_hpet object: in this case, the HPET chip is the source of
>   timer interrupts. The mark_offset method checks that no timer interrupt has been lost
>   since the last tick; in this unlikely case, it updates jiffies_64 accordingly.

So, can anyone shed a light on how can the linux kernel keep track of time in case tick interrupts are lost? what does 'accordingly' stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just read the HPET value. The interrupts are useful, but not required.

"update jiffies_64 accordingly" would mean to set it to the value it should have had, if interrupts weren't lost.

Comment: ok but it still does not answer the main question. lets say the HPET is not the clock source, the kernel should provide reliable clock to the processes. So if I disable tick interrupts, and the data structures of the kernel related to timers does not updated (jiffies, xtimer...) how can the mark_offset() function can recover the lost ticks?

Comment: @user2162550: If you want to know for *certain* you will have to read the Linux timer code. In every case without a periodic tick, the kernel needs an external time source. That can be HPET, TSC or I suppose some form of real-time clock. If nothing is available then either time will be wrong or you won't be able to disable tick interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

The full paragram is as following, please note **last sentence**.

> cur_timer points to the timer_hpet object: in this case, the HPET chip is the
>   source of timer interrupts. The mark_offset method checks that no timer
>   interrupt has been lost since the last tick; in this unlikely case, it updates
>   jiffies_64 accordingly. **Next, the method records the current value of the
>   periodic HPET counter.**

jiffies_64 is increased by one for each timer interrupt (a tick). So if timer interrupt is disabled for several ticks, jiffies_64 would not be able to increase for several times, thus lost track the time. So how to keep jiffies_64 updated while timer interrupt is disabled?

It's for sure jiffies_64 is **not** be updated when timer interrupt is disabled. So it may lost a few ticks **temporarily**.

But it will be corrected at next timer interrupt and it's done by cur_timer->mark_offset(). Remember mark_offset() records the ***exact time*** of last tick. It's worth to note that the ***exact time*** is not the time maintained by kernel, but it is maintained by timer chip. A **timer chip** is an *independent* chip which has a counter driven by its OWN clock and increase by one each clock. The chip's timer interrupt may be disabled, its counter keep increasing. And the *exact time* is not really a time, but the chip's **counter**! So in each timer interrupt, mark_offset() save timer chip's counter. Before saving counter, mark_offset() compare last time saved counter with current timer chip's counter to see if there is timer interrupt has been lost.

Suppose timer chip's counter is increased by one each time a timer interrupt is generated. So if no timer interrupt is lost, mark_offset() saved counter plus 1 should equal to current timer's counter at the time mark_offset() try to save chip's counter in timer interrupt handler. If not equal, then timer interrupt is lost, by comparing the difference between saved counter and chip's counter, we will know how many interrupts are lost. Since jiffies_64 is increased by one for each timer interrupt, we know how much need to be added to jiffies_64, thus updates jiffies_64 accordingly.

Please note the lost timer interrupt can only be found if timer chip has a counter. This is true for HPET but not true for PIT chip. For PIT chip, I guess it's lost.

reference in Understanding the Linux Kernel.
mark_offset() P233,
jiffies_64 P234,
xtime P235,
mark_offset() in interrupt handler P237